# A facade root has not been set. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

intenté hacer una instalación de [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) vía composer, no sé si eso haya causado el problema o lo que estaba desarrollando (afectó a todas mis ramas, excepto a master pero master tiene solamente el proyecto inicial de laravel sin nada más) y ahora tengo el siguiente problema en la consola

```
In Facade.php line 258:

A facade root has not been set.
```

Y en los Logs

```
[2022-03-05 14:42:04] laravel.ERROR: A facade root has not been set. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): A facade root has not been set. at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:258)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/config/forrest.php(33): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(72): require('...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(237): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#6 /var/www/html/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#7 {main}
"}
```

En la pantalla del proyecto:

```
RuntimeException
A facade root has not been set.

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php
```

- no puedo ejecutar comandos artisan de cache ni clear.
- ya intenté hacer composer update y cuando toca hacer autoload, aparece el mismo error
- haciendo composer dump-autoload solamente también
- eliminar debugbar y hacer composer install también tira el error al hacer dump-autoload

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al hacer cualquier cosa con composer, instala, actualiza o downgradea dependiendo de lo que haga, pero cuando toca hacer el autoload también ocurre el problema

qué podría ser?

**NOTA: ya hasta descargué nuevamente el proyecto y sigue igual**

Estoy pensando en eliminar todo lo de composer y volver a instalarlo, pero no estoy seguro cómo o dónde se encuentra.
estoy usando [Ubuntu-20.04](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-2004/9n6svws3rx71?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0) corriendo sobre [docker](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/) en windows y usando windows terminal

este es mi config/app.php completo

```
    <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
    | framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
    | any other location as required by the application or its packages.
    |
    */

    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services the application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => (bool)env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Faker Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This locale will be used by the Faker PHP library when generating fake
    | data for your database seeds. For example, this will be used to get
    | localized telephone numbers, street address information and more.
    |
    */

    'faker_locale' => 'en_US',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Google Geocoder Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used to get latitude and longitude values
    | for an address that values are strings
    |
    |
    */

    'GOOGLE_GEOCODER_API_KEY' => env('GOOGLE_GEOCODER_API_KEY'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        \Omniphx\Forrest\Providers\Laravel\ForrestServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\JetstreamServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Arr' => Illuminate\Support\Arr::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'Date' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Date::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Http' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::class,
        'Js' => Illuminate\Support\Js::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'RateLimiter' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        // 'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'Forrest' => \Omniphx\Forrest\Providers\Laravel\Facades\Forrest::class,
    ],

];
```

contenido de config/forrest.php línea 32 y 33

```
        // Only required for OAuthJWT authentication:
    'privateKey'     => Storage::disk('local')->get('SalesforceKeys/area_check.key'),
```

sí tengo el archivo /area_check.key en storage/app/SalesforceKeys

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes agregar el contenido de tu `config/app.php` y el logger?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato actualicé la pregunta con el config, el logger? los logs? ya están los logs, el logger no sé que es

Comment: Proba borrando la cache, todo lo que haya en bootstrap/cache

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ he borrado todo lo que está en boostrap/cache pero sigue igual, solamente tengo bootstrap/app.php

Comment: Que hay en config/forrest.php linea 33?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ un storage::disk para obtener el contenido de un archivo .key guardado en el storage

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ eso viene funcionando así desde el 24 de febrero, todos los días usamos esa key en producción para una sincronización automática, no creo que esto esté ocasionando algo

Comment: Probaste sacarlo y te sigue lanzando la misma excepción pero en otro archivo?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ saqué la línea para poner directamente la clave en el .php y ya funcionan los comandos y composer, pero mi proyecto no levanta, localhost no envió ningún dato.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ de todas maneras cuando solucione esto para levantar el proyecto, seguramente tendré que mejorar la manera de obtener esa key. Cuál crees que sea la mejor forma? no sé si sea buena idea en el .env porque es muy larga y tiene saltos de línea

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ logré levantar el proyecto, reemplacé esa línea cambiándola a env('SF_CRT_KEY'), y he puesto la key en el .env, no me agrada mucho así porque es muy larga, crees que hay una mejor manera? o la dejo así?

Comment: No sé bien en qué momento es que necesitas esa key, pero se me ocurre que en el archivo config puedes dejar sólo el path al archivo `'privateKey' => 'SalesforceKeys/area_check.key'`, y la facade Storage sólo usarla cuando realmente necesites el contenido del archivo `Storage::disk('local')->get(config('archivo.privateKey'))`. O lo mismo si lo haces en el .env, pones el path al archivo en una variable, y luego en tu código lo obtienes de ahí `Storage::disk('local')->get(env('PrivateKey'))`